# Looking for a possible trilogy from the 2000s which starts with siblings who are put under a spell to fall in love

Tags: story-identification, books

The first book is about siblings who are put under a spell to fall in love. The brother finds out and is horrified. The girl is a redhead and is very powerful. There is some kind of rebellion and a war. They use the girl for her powers by putting a collar on her.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you mean that they were spelled to fall in love _with one another_?  Do you remember any details of the books, like the cover art, format or how long they were?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Yes. They were spelled to fall in love with one another. I think one of them over heard a conversation about it in a rebel base. The boy hated her when he found out but the girl loved him anyway. I don’t think they were blood relatives. She ended up being used for her powers and had a collar put on her but she was so powerful she was able to make it disintegrate.

Comment: I don’t think the book had any otherworldly beings in it. They were just humans I think. I have no idea about the covers. For some reason I cannot remember them at all.

Answer (score 9):

This sounds likes a partial match to *[The Elvenbane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Halfblood_Chronicles)* by Andre Norton and Mercedes Lackey.

What matches:

- It has a red-headed girl (Shana) who is an extremely powerful half-elven magic user. She partially falls in love with her elven half-brother (not really, but he thinks she is) who is horrified by the thought and I think uses magic to try and get her to fall in love with her cousin (another half-elf).
- She has a slave collar put on her that suppresses her human magic by some people who captured her as a slave, but they didn't have using her for magic in mind.
- There is a rebellion/war between the half-elves wizards (who had been hiding) and the elven lords.
- It is the first of a trilogy.

Some things that might make this not a match

- Shape changing dragons
- She was adopted at birth by a dragon shaman, and has an adopted brother (who is a dragon.)